# Getting an entry before and after a given entry in a Django Queryset

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple blog as part of a website and I am getting stuck on something that I am assuming is simple.

If I call any blog post, say by it's title, from a queryset, how can I get the entry before and after the post in it's published order.

I can iterate over the whole thing, get the position of the entry I have and use that to call the one before and the one after.  But that is a long bit of code for something that I am sure I can do more simply.

What I want would be something like this:

```
next_post = Posts.object.filter(title=current_title).order_by("-published")[-1]
```

Of course because of the filter, it is not going to work, but just to give you the idea of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Posts.get_{next,previous}_by_FOO()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO).

Comment: I didn't get the method described to work, but it did help me search a little better.  What I finally got working was:

Posts.objects.order_by('published').filter(published__lt=FOO.published)[0]
and substitute published__lt for published__gt

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/602d74da27cadf83